# i want to know this code is secure or not ? if it's not secure then what will do?

Tags: ios, ssl

**i have make connection in ssl with socket.but i am confuse its secure or not? please anyone describe it secure or not if it is not secure then what will do? **

```
(void)connection{

uint portNo = 443;
CFReadStreamRef readStream;
CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;

CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)@"myipaddress", portNo, &readStream, &writeStream);
inputStream = (__bridge NSInputStream *)readStream;
outputStream = (__bridge NSOutputStream *)writeStream;

[inputStream setDelegate:self];
[outputStream setDelegate:self];

[inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[inputStream open];
[outputStream open];
[inputStream setProperty:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL forKey:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelKey];
[outputStream setProperty:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL forKey:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelKey];

NSDictionary *setting=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],
                        kCFStreamSSLAllowsExpiredCertificates,
                        [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], kCFStreamSSLAllowsAnyRoot,
                        [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], kCFStreamSSLValidatesCertificateChain,
                        kCFNull, kCFStreamSSLPeerName,
                        nil ];

CFReadStreamSetProperty((CFReadStreamRef)readStream, kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings, (CFTypeRef)setting);
CFReadStreamSetProperty((CFReadStreamRef)writeStream, kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings, (CFTypeRef)setting);
```

}

Comment: Secure over the network? if you have 256 bit ssl then no worries about it.

Comment: Secure against what? The SSL checks aren't exactly comprehensive...

Comment: Retro,how to use 256 bit ssl onto the network